# What method(s) should I use to achive statistical ranking?

Tags: r, regression, forecasting, computational-statistics

I'm attempting a project where I need to statistically rank available cars based on several variables such as cost, mpg, seating, milage, etc.. I wish to rank these cars in order decide which car would be the best choice (highest "worth") to buy (or best several cars if I was informing multiple people of the best cars to get). As the list of available cars changes from day to day, I will also need to re-run the code every day to allow the rankings to give me the best decision for this new day.

What statistical methods should I use to go about this ranking system? I plan on determining which factors I find most important so the variables used will be subjective in choice. I thought about trying MDS or clustering but I didn't know if that would be relevant since I'm already subjectively determining what variables are to be used. I don't see how regression can be used since I can't get a handle on the "worth" of previous cars as that is what I'm trying to rank by. Also, I will be attempting this in R so any helpful packages/functions would be great to know as well.

Any help with how to go about this ranking scheme would be helpful as I'm at a loss.

Thanks so much

Comment: The answer [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9358/creating-an-index-of-quality-from-multiple-variables-to-enable-rank-ordering/9361#9361) may be of interest.