# log transformation with the self-reported health score variables

Tags: logarithm, transform, variable

With self-reported health scores (as a dependent variable) - such as CES-D for depression which typically ranges from 0 to 60, I was wondering whether log-transforming these scores would allow me to interpret their coefficient as a **%** change.

My point is that although these scores provide valuable information, it is often unclear what "12 CES-D points" of change would practically mean. In addition, since they are not interval variables, often scores tend to be concentrated within particular range.

Conversely, I thought that log-transforming these dependent variables would allow me to partially *flatten* their distribution and - more importantly - interpret their change more intuitively.
For instance, while it is unclear what 7 point CES-D decrease would mean, 10% decrease in CES-D score can perhaps be construed as similar decrease in their depression symptom.

I believe there are few articles tackling with these transformation issues, but it seems that there no apparent reason not to perform analysis this way.

Any ideas?!

Comment: If it's unclear what a score means, why would it be any clearer what its logarithm means?  There are ways to assign numbers to *ordinal* variables like scores, but they require you to associate the scores with other values in order to accomplish that.  There is a *huge* literature on identifying useful transformations of data.  A good place to start is the older literature on exploratory data analysis going back to Tukey's 1977 book *EDA.*

Comment: Hi @Whuber. Would love to hear you comment more on some of the methods you know for transforming ordinal variables into continuous scores. I know of a few such as 'ridit scoring' or perhaps estimating a latent continuous variable. But, if you know this area well, would love to hear some further suggestions

Comment: A good search keyword is [ordinal regression.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=ordinal+regression+score%3A2). A completely different line of attack is exemplified by "multi-attribute valuation theory," or MAVT.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/9361/919 for a quick summary of the latter.